# Sound wave in relativistic perfect fluid

Tags: special-relativity, fluid-dynamics, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I was trying to solve the following problem from the problem book on relativty:

Problem 5.22. Show that the velocity of sound $v_{s}$ in a relativistic perfect fluid is given by
$$v_{s}^{2}=\partial p /\left.\partial \rho\right|_{s=c o n s t a n t}$$

For a high temperature relativistic gas with an equation of state $\rho \approx 3 \mathrm{P}$
(essentially that for a photon gas) show that $v_{s} \approx 1 / \sqrt{3}$

Solution is given as:

Solution $5.22 .$ Assume that the acoustical wave is a perturbation
(isentropic) in a uniform static fluid with parameters $\rho_{0}, P_{0},$ and $n_{0}$
Let the perturbations be $\rho_{1}, P_{1},$ and $n_{1}$ and the fluid velocity be
$\mathbf{u} \approx\left(1, \underline{v}_{1}\right)$ in the rest frame of the unperturbed fluid. The first order perturbation terms in $\mathrm{T}_{, \nu}^{\mu \nu}=0$ give us

(i) From $\mu=0$
$$\nabla \cdot \underline{v}_{1}=-\frac{\partial \rho_{1}}{\partial t}\left(\rho_{0}+P_{0}\right)^{-1}$$

(ii) From $\mu=1,2,3$

$$\frac{\partial \underline{v}_{1}}{\partial \mathrm{t}}=-\frac{\nabla \mathrm{P}_{1}}{\left(\rho_{0}+\mathrm{P}_{0}\right)}$$
which can be combined into
$$\partial^{2} \rho_{1} / \partial t^{2}-\nabla^{2} P_{1}=0$$
since $P_{1}$ and $\rho_{1}$ are related for isentropic flow by

Can anyone explain or derive the equation given in (ii).

Comment: did you start with the stress-energy tensor for a perfect fluid and try taking the covariant derivative?